# Why does CustomBadge draws text in black color in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7

Just updated to iOS 7 my project, solving warning deprecations like sizeWithFont:

before:

```
CGSize stringSize = [badgeString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
```

after:

```
CGSize stringSize = [badgeString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]}];
```

and the text color becomes black:
[image]

Any ideas?

the code than drawns the text is:

```
[badgeTextColor set];
CGFloat sizeOfFont = 13.5*badgeScaleFactor;
if ([self.badgeText length]<2) {
    sizeOfFont += sizeOfFont*0.20;
}
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:sizeOfFont];

CGSize textSize = [self.badgeText sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:textFont,
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.badgeTextColor}];

[self.badgeText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((rect.size.width/2-textSize.width/2), (rect.size.height/2-textSize.height/2)) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textFont}];
```

I've add `NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.badgeTextColor` but it doesn't work

before... `[self.badgeTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor]];`

Comment: And do you explicitly set the text colour to something else?

Comment: Yes by default is white, I'll add code

Answer (score 1):

I've solved, I had a mistake in my own solution, is correct to add this 
`NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.badgeTextColor}`

but not in `textSize` initialization

It must be in `[self.badteTxt draw....`

```
[self.badgeText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((rect.size.width/2-textSize.width/2),
(rect.size.height/2-textSize.height/2)) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textFont,
NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.badgeTextColor}];
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for this. I had ported but didn't include the second dictionary key/value.